# how to calculate the bots percentage of a discord server (nodejs)?

Tags: node.js

I want to calculate the percentage of bots/users of a discord server.

Specs:
nodejs: v16
discord.js: v13

Why I want it:
Because i want to do a partner bot and i want to calculate the percentage of users and bots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple math, add them thogether, and check it...

```
function percentage(partialValue, totalValue) {
   return (100 * partialValue) / totalValue;
} 

const guilds = *your guilds*
const users = *your users*
const all = guilds + users

// to check users

const users = await percentage(users, all)

console.log(`${users}%`)
// if users are 80% it will result with 80, and the rest would be guilds :)
```